# Joining two files

Tags: text-processing, join

I have a 2 files with the following:

```
File1.txt 
A 1
B 2
C 5
Z 3

File2.txt
A 4
B 7 
C 10
D 11
```

What I would like to do is create something like

```
A 1 4 
B 2 7
C 5 10
D - 11
Z 3 -
```

Is there a utility that does this? If not how Can this be done? Using a `find` and `awk` or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
join -a1 -a2 -o 0,1.2,2.2 -e - file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: Does This require that the files be sorted in order?

Comment: @StenKin, yes, the inputs must be sorted on the join keys (here the first column).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ join File1.txt File2.txt
```

*almost* does what you want - but it only displays lines which have a matching key.

It's easy enough to script the result you want, but I don't know a single utility that does it exactly.